# reactJS routing, errors 500 & .htaccess: rewrite rules not working on sub-routes

Tags: reactjs, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, routes

I built a react app based on [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app).

In the package.json, I used '.' as value for the homepage:

```
{
    ...
    "homepage": ".",
    ...
}
```

But when deployed, I had 500 server errors; which [I fixed by adding some htaccess stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57271732/782013); on the top of a rewrite rule to force HTTPS:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    #force HTTPS
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    #fix 500 errors
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule . /$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

This seems to works for urls like

> mywebsite.com

> mywebsite.com/component

but not for sub-routes like

> mywebsite.com/component/something

Those do fire various errors like for instance

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' - main.8f4fdfb2.chunk.js:1

I noticed that opening this file (or any asset) on the server loads in fact the index.html file; because of the rewrite rule of the .htaccess, I suppose.

How should I update my .htaccess file so it only redirects the "main" request to index.html and not the assets ?

Thanks !

Comment: The RewriteConds check that what was requested does not match a physically existing file, folder or symbolic link - so if you are talking about static assets here, this should not affect them to begin with. Unclear though what you expect `$1` to be, when your RewriteRule doesn’t even _capture_ anything?

Comment: This is somethinig I did copy/paste.  Don't know much about rewrite rules...  But have a look at https://v2.spiff-radio.org/wizard/eyJ1cmwiOiJhcnRpc3Q6d2V2YWw6c2ltaWxhciJ9, and check the console : you'll see that the assets are not correctly loaded. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Try and make that last rule `RewriteRule . /index.html [L]`, and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Hi, I did the test; doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it by changing

```
"homepage": ".",
```

to

```
"homepage": "",
```

in my *package.json*.

Also found out interesting informations about that problem in this article: [An elegant solution of deploying React app into a subdirectory](https://skryvets.com/blog/2018/09/20/an-elegant-solution-of-deploying-react-app-into-a-subdirectory/), where they suggest to add

```
<base href="%PUBLIC_URL%/">
```

in the `<head/>` section of your *index.html*; but in my case it seems to work without this  line.

For the record, [this gist](https://gist.github.com/alexsasharegan/173878f9d67055bfef63449fa7136042) has been useful too.